# Facebook Accountkit api error using ionicframework 2 - The api version is not supported TAAL[BLAME_func,invariant_violation] TAAL[BLAME_file])

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to implement the facebook accountkit using javascript. I followed the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/web/integrating. 
I used ionic 2.

Implementing the Account Kit Javascript SDK, Accountkit.init works fine. But when i call the method AccountKit.login, the error pops up.

The error says

> *The api version is not supported TAAL[BLAME_func,invariant_violation] TAAL[BLAME_file]*

The redirected popup URL address  is like this.

```
https://www.accountkit.com/v2.6/dialog/sms_login/?app_id={{facebook_app_id}}&country_code={{countryCode}}&locale=ko_KR&logging_ref=f288b0578b6851&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100&phone_number={{phoneNumber}}&sdk=web&state=csrf&version=v2.6
```

Why is this error happening? 
I read all of the facebook accountkit document, but I couldn't find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using v1.0 . I was getting the same error but v1.0 fall back worked for me.

Comment: [I wonder if you could you help me with this problem..... the login form doesn't appear :(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720128/facebook-accountkit-javascript-mobile-form-not-showing-ios-9-3) @kinaan

Comment: Could you kindly share your code? I'm stuck on a similar problem in Ionic 2 with Account Kit. Code doesnt work when using localhost, but it works when uploaded to server.

Comment: have you provided correct `Server URLs`  in account kit app setting ?