# Facebook Accountkit Javascript mobile form not showing - iOS 9.3

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic2, ios9.3

I am trying to implement the facebook accountkit using javascript.

I've solved the 'api is not supported' error by using the Accountkit version: v1.0

It works fine on PC, [but it has an error on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pP2o.png). The form of country_number and phone_number is not showing on iOS. I've tested in safari, chrome app, ionic webview.

[image: but it has an error on iOS]

You can also test on this url : http://www.purepeople.co.kr:8888

How can I show the AccountKit login form on iphone?

Comment: it is working fine right now. I have checked it on iOS 9.3

Comment: I rebooted my phone.. and it works.. Thanks again!!